# Create new Node with Relationship to existing Node

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4J and I'm just playing around with it and get used to it.

I have an existing Node with the label **User** and a property **name** thats set to **daniel**. Now I want to create a new Node **Message** that has a relationship **Send**.

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.name = 'daniel'
CREATE (m:Message {text = 'hallo welt'} )-[:Send]-(u)
```

But the Neo4J-Browser just returns "Unknown error". Can someone point out what's wrong with this statement?

Comment: also there might be a ..)-[:Send]->(u) (missing right arrow)

Comment: no. that didn't help. besides i want a bidirectional relationship.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Colon instead of equals sign in the CREATE.
Also there are no undirected rels in Neo4j but you can choose to ignore direction at query time.

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.name = 'daniel'
CREATE (m:Message {text : 'hallo welt'} )<-[:SENT]-(u)
```

see: http://console.neo4j.org/r/4q8r92

Comment: Urgs... Thank you! Why doesn't the "browser" point that out? :(